# How to handle FSharpOption object in javascript

Tags: f#

I'm using web api to send a list of an FSharp records to be put in a kendo grid

```ml
[<DataContract>]
type MyClass = {
   [<field: DataMember(Name="Foo")>]
   Foo: int
   [<field: DataMember(Name="Bar")>]
   Bar: DateTime option
}
```

```
$.getJSON(myUrl).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   ds.data(data);
   var grid = $('#myGrid').data("kendoGrid");
   grid.setDataSource(ds);
```

When I see it in the grid, the int displays fine, but the "Bar" does not.
In the console:

```
Bar: Object
--Case: "Some"
--Fields: Array[1]
----0: "2014-12-18T17:01:34.0071449Z"
```

How do I handle this type of object in javascript? Or treat it like a nullable object?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with it?

Comment: My goal is just to display it in a grid; I'm not doing anything else with it. I've searched here and with search engines but no luck in this subject

Comment: I mean, do you want to filter out `None` items or display an empty box or...?

Comment: If FSharpOption.None, then the cell will be empty (treat like null). If FSharpOption.Some, there will be only 1 item, and I want to display that item

Comment: Probably best to do a transform on the data before putting it in the grid.

Comment: Do you mean in javascript or pass in a different class that doesn't have FSharpOption?

Comment: Probably whichever makes more sense.  Generally speaking, I would avoid passing F# specific types to non-F# languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, its best to avoid passing F#-specific types (like discriminated unions) to non-F# languages.  You could perhaps use your data contract to transform your data into a more usable form during serialization.  If you are using json.net you can use the examples [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm).